# Object not rotating around its axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a gun consisting of two parts (1 is handle, 2 is nozzle). I want to rotate the nozzle when I shoot the target.

[image: I want to rotate the Nozzle like this]

I am using following code of line inside my fire function

```
gunNozzle.transform.Rotate(0, 0, 10);
```

It is increasing the rotation value, but the result is different. Here is complete function:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P))
    {
        isOut = true;
    }
    if (isOut)
    {     
        playerAnim.CrossFade("gunplays", 0.03f);
        gunNozzle.transform.Rotate(0, 0, 10);
        audioSource.Play();
        GameObject cloneArrow = (GameObject)Instantiate(theArrow, thePos, Quaternion.identity);
        cloneArrow.transform.position = thePos;
        cloneArrow.transform.rotation = this.transform.rotation;
        isOut = false;
    }
}
```

It seems to be a simple thing, but I am stuck.

Here is the result:

[image: Here is the result of the above code]

Comment: What does "the result is different" mean?

Comment: means, no rotation in the Nozzle, i have added result also, please check once..

Comment: If you see my first gif, when i rotate manually through interface, the value of 'z' is increasing and along with it, the position of x and position of y is also getting changed.

Comment: Is this just the anim gifs, or the whole thing runs super-slow? Latter case would indicate something is coded terribly wrong here. Did you try to make the gun work without the character? Place the gun GO somewhere on the scene (an empty project would be the best), add the script to it that spawns bullets and animate barrel rotation when triggered, and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Your parameters to transform.Rotate don't looks correct to me. Should be something like

```
gunNozzle.transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime);
```

Nb: Vector direction might be wrong in my example.

Comment: Also are you sure that gunNozzle is set to the correct object, and it is not perhaps rotating something else off-screen?

Comment: Sorry, no no, my laser direction gets changed by some degree, i have tried with different directions also..no result

Comment: try replacing with gunNozzle.SetActive(false);  This should hide the gun barrel. If it doesn't then the 'gunNozzle' object is not set to the correct object (or that piece of code is not firing - perhaps try adding a console log statement also)

Answer (score 0):

Try including either Space.Self or Space.World in Rotate()