# Fixed the position of Gun

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My gun position is not getting fixed, it is moving with rotation. Please see in the below pic.

[image: Please see image]

I am using the following code:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
{
    if (countICR < 50)
    {
        GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Gun").transform.Rotate(-8 * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        countICR++;
        countDCR--;
    }
}

if (Input.GetMouseButton(2))
{
    if (countDCR < 50)
    {
        GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Gun").transform.Rotate(8 * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        countDCR++;
        countICR--;
    }
}
```

I have also tried using Rigidbody attached to the gun and freezing the position (all coordinates), but it still is changing.

I want the gun to be fixed at the handle side and the other parts should move up and down.

Comment: So just to get this clear:
When the player turns, the gun turns as well. When the gun rotates, the stock needs to stay in the same position but the rest should move with the hands. Seems like something that should be done through an animation rather than through code. You'll have a hard time making it look good otherwise

Comment: Followup to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39958230/object-not-rotating-around-its-axis)

Comment: @sokkyoku - yes, when the player turns, the guns turns. I have tried using mouse movement code attached with the hands, the hands does not move at all. if same code is attached with gun, then gun moves but it gets separated from the body of the player. please help i need this very urgent..  and to -> Manfred - yes, the same question was posted by me and i did not get any answer, please help

Comment: I would use FindChild instead (as it's much cheaper) as well as I would store the ref. as a member var instead of calling Find in Update(). As of the question, what holds you back from adding empty GOs to the gun and use them as rotation points (stock: up/down: follows player hand GO, left/right: follows player's 'y' if has to as not child of player for some reason), barrel end point (where bullet spawns), etc?

Answer (score 2):

remove the script.. that is what makes the gun rotate ;)

you simply dont want the gun to rotate (so why script it?). you want the character to rotate, and the gun to listen.

make the gun a child of where it is supposed to be fixed to ( example: the hand ),
then rotate the arm. the hand will follow, as will the gun.

ps: if you want to make it look good, use animations.